# Plotly subplots and graph objects error: Trace type 'scatter3d' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy' at grid position

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I get this error when I try to add_trace to a sunbplots. The plot is a graph objects object.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows = len(dfbh['client'].value_counts().index.tolist()), cols = 1)
scatbh = go.Scatter3d(x=dfbhtemp['x_local'], y=dfbhtemp['y_local'], z=dfbhtemp['z_local'], mode = 'markers', )
scatrun = go.Scatter3d(x=dfrunstemp['x_local'], y=dfrunstemp['y_local'], z=dfrunstemp['z_local'], mode = 'markers')
fig.add_trace(scatbh, row = 1, col = 1)
fig.add_trace(scatrun, row = 1, col = 1)
fig.show()

ValueError:  Trace type 'scatter3d' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy'
at grid position (2, 1)
```

These plots plot normaly when using subplots with no rows or columns.

Comment: From what I can see, you need to extract the items out of the graph object and replot. Seems silly though.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error and the following worked for me: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3315#issuecomment-1164393438

You need to specify the chart type in the `specs` argument of the `make_subplots` function. Below is an example a 2x2 subplot figure.

```py
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, 
    cols=2,
    start_cell="top-left", 
    specs=[
        [{"type": "scatter3d"}, {"type": "scatter3d"}], 
        [{"type": "scatter3d"}, {"type": "scatter3d"}]
    ]
)
```

Comment: Ex.: `specs = [[{"type": "scatter3d"} for _ in range(0, cols)] for _ in range(0, rows)]` since outer list = rows, inner lists = columns (see [reference](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html#plotly.subplots.make_subplots))